# Find all Subgraphs using the reflexive transitive closure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Python code which finds the transitive closure.

**Example:**

Input: {('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','D'),('E','F')}

Output: {('B', 'C'), **('A', 'D')**, ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), **('B', 'D')**, ('E', 'F'), **('A', 'C')**}

The code *works perfect*, but what I'm looking for is to have the output as a set of subgraphs. I'm a beginner in Python, and I'm not sure how to do that.

According to the given input, here is the output that I'm looking for, which has two elements in the set each represents a subgraph from the transitive closure output: **{(A, B, C, D), (E, F)}**

Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transitive_closure(elements):
    edges = defaultdict(set)
    # map from first element of input tuples to "reachable" second elements
    for x, y in elements: edges[x].add(y)

    for _ in range(len(elements) - 1):
        edges = defaultdict(set, (
                                  (k, v.union(*(edges[i] for i in v)))
                                  for (k, v) in edges.items()
                                  ))

    return set((k, i) for (k, v) in edges.items() for i in v)

result = set(transitive_closure([('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','D'),('E','F')]))
print result
```

Comment: What you want is not well defined (at least it's not clear). What do you mean "as the longest possible paths". For example what will you want the output to be for the following input: {('A','B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A), ('A', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('D', 'F')} ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to me; why didn't you post it as a comment?

Comment: but what about the case I asked for? When you have a cycle or a tree with branches - then what do you want? Your question is not well defined is what I am trying to say. And this is  my answer - no one can answer a not well defined question.

Comment: ['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'F'], that's the result for your sample. I got that, I shouldn't say PATH. For sure there will be cycles, which will lead to infinite loops. Now I'll modify my question.

Comment: It isn't clear what subgraphs you are looking for. Are you looking for connected components?

Comment: Connected components as the example suggests

Comment: Then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using **networkx** in Python. **networkx** provides a functionality to find all sub-graphs of a given one.

All I needed is to have the output of the **transitive_closure()** method, translate it to a graph for networkx and then having the new created graph as an input to the **connected_component_subgraphs()** method provided by networkx.

```
H=nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
```

H is a set contains all sub-graphs needed.

The main drawback is processing time, but that's the best I could find.